# Handling Data based on Source Authority C#/SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I struggled to find a good title. Let me explain the challenge:

- A C# service can receive data (class Weather), from multiple clients.
- Let's assume 2 clients only for this example.
- Class Weather has 3 properties: Temperature, Humidity and Visibility.
- The service receives data from client 1 and stores it in SQL (90 degrees, 60%, 6 miles)
- Later, the service receives data from client 2 (92 degrees, 60%, 5 miles)
- The service (or SQL) needs to decide whether to overwrite the values or not.
- The service knows that client 1 is trustworthy when it comes to Temperature and Humidity and that client 2 is trustworthy for Visibility.
- the outcome should be that the service updates the data to be:
  90 degrees (originally from client 1)
  60% (originally from client 1)
  5 miles (update from client 2)

Any ideas on how to approach this design/implementation? 
any patterns? 
implement the decision in the service? or in SQL?

The only approach I could think of is brute:

if (data came from client 1)
   overwrite Temperature and Humidity in the db. 
   store Visibility only if it's not set yet in the db.

if (data came from client 2)
   overwrite Visibility in the db.
   store Temperature and humidity if they're not set yet in the db.

But I feel there may be a better way to do this.

Thanks!